# Laravel 4.2 email configuration with mail driver on local

Tags: php, email, laravel, xampp

i'm using xampp and want to send email with laravel 4.2 mail driver on local machine. But nothings happen. somebody can help?

```
return array(

  'driver' => 'mail',

  'host' => 'localhost',

  'port' => 25,

  'from' => array('address' => 'foo@bar.com', 'name' => 'foo'),

  'encryption' => 'tls',

  'username' => '',

  'password' => '',

  'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

  'pretend' => false,
);
```

Comment: use ur gmail in `username` and ur gmail password as `password`

Comment: thanks for the response. yeah i know, that's work fine. but i want the driver is mail